# Manage Play Framework dependencies in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.0

I created a project from Play Framework. And after eclipsifing  the project I imported in to eclipse IDE.
`Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.Version: Kepler Service Release 1`

after that the java build path libraries are shown in the main directory as below in the picture.

[image]

It is very annoying that I have to scroll down it when i need to access the folders like `project` , `public` since they are located after the jar files.

Is there any way I can move the jar files to a separate location (probably with the name `external references` or something) like the 'JRE System Library' in the below image.

[image]

Comment: I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) and it's working fine (jar are automatically shown in a separate folder 'Referenced Libraries'). Maybe this is an issue because you are using the EE Eclipse and Play is definitely not Java EE. Another thing you could try is to clean the project in eclipse.

Comment: why did you said `Play is definitely not Java EE` ? And I'll try another version of eclipse. Thank you.

Comment: Because Play tries to tackle the development in another much leaner way than Java EE with its servlets approach does. So that there is a infinite event-loop in the back instead of block-io access and not need a layer above servlets to map url directly to actions. Describing the whole thing is too much for a short comment here, but a short motivation for play can be found here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Philosophy